# generate "dynamic" random variables?

Tags: random, distributions

I have the following problem:
I generated two random numbers

```
y = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.5], 2]
s = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[.1], 2]

l = y.s
```

I want to generate in a loop 100 times the product `l` but I do not know how

```
Table[l, {i, 1, 100}]
```

It means that $y$ and $s$ should be generated 100 times each.

Comment: Try `l := y.s` and report back.

Comment: `Table[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.5], 2].RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[.1], 2],{100}]`

Comment: @J.M. thanks but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I know that but I would have it in a more "dynamical" way I would lave such a way that every time when I call `l` it generates a pair again! Thanks any way

Comment: @maniA:  Try running my code several times....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the definitions of $y$, $s$, and $l$ are re-evaluated every time you invoke them, so new random numbers are generated every time.

Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in their definition to accomplish that:

```
Clear[y, s, l]
y := RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.5], 2]
s := RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[.1], 2]
l := y.s

Table[l, {100}]
```

> {10.7424, 7.25643, 1.79782, 0., 0., 0., 0., 6.39046, 19.2634, 0., 
>   3.64775, 42.3379, 29.0361, 2.55506, 1.88215, 10.3919, 8.3307, 
>   15.2387, 0., 26.3855, 9.85697, 0., 7.19747, 13., 23.0351, 11.9228, 
>   13.1692, 13.9306, 20.5389, 5.8673, 0., 1.19822, 19.6213, 11.4207, 
>   4.82677, 5.45082, 0.695063, 5.96605, 5.7171, 16.1679, 32.8879, 
>   29.0086, 25.1448, 0., 4.4569, 34.8751, 30.3961, 19.9085, 11.085, 
>   1.0612, 1.35964, 1.46275, 9.38037, 0., 7.50795, 1.98857, 0., 28.8082, 
>   37.2276, 0., 0., 0., 6.14201, 34.8584, 0., 3.46096, 6.27206, 73.3928, 
>   76.495, 1.91647, 13.1031, 30.1474, 1.64898, 0., 0., 31.3811, 
>   0.0756431, 0., 20.0724, 11.7921, 5.37092, 22.8973, 10.3185, 4.998, 
>   5.84697, 0.537638, 14.6865, 17.3023, 11.0843, 0., 3.27186, 0., 
>   3.34524, 11.12, 16.9808, 2.14918, 14.7753, 4.76471, 0., 3.78329}

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the straightforward approach in Marco's answer, you can instead derive a `TransformedDistribution[]` that can be used within `RandomVariate[]`:

```
bd = BernoulliDistribution[1/2]; ed = ExponentialDistribution[1/10];
td = TransformedDistribution[b1 e1 + b2 e2,
                             {b1 \[Distributed] bd, b2 \[Distributed] bd,
                              e1 \[Distributed] ed, e2 \[Distributed] ed}];
```

and then do `RandomVariate[td, 100]`.